# Yahoo is unable to process your request 95022, OAuth2 authentication error

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, xamarin, yahoo-api

I'm trying to use Yahoo's developer APIs in Xamarin Studio's Xamarin Auth component.  I created my app in with Yahoo's Developer tools, set my permissions to read everything, but can't get authorization.  I get the following error.

Oops.  Yahoo is unable to process your request.  We recommend that you contact the owner of the application or web site to resolve this issue. [95022]

Below is my code

```
        string clientId = "<application id from developer.apps.yahoo.com>";
        string scope = "";
        Uri authorizeUrl = new Uri("https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth");
        Uri redirectUrl = new Uri("http://www.website.com");
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(clientId, scope, authorizeUrl, redirectUrl);

        auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
            Console.WriteLine("eventArgs.IsAuthenticated = " + eventArgs.IsAuthenticated);
            DismissViewController (true, null);
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated) {
                // Use eventArgs.Account to do wonderful things

            }
        };


        PresentViewController(auth.GetUI(), true, null);
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

**-------------- Update --------------**

I wasn't able to get OAuth2 in Xamarin.Auth working with Yahoo, but I did get OAuth1 functional.  I ended up not even using that component and instead using another implementation of OAuth that was documented in the Yahoo Developer Documentation with OAuth and BOSS found here

[Using OAuth with BOSS API](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/oauth_model.html)